# "start" command in .bat batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have an extremely simply batch file, which has previously worked for me but no longer will.

```
start /wait steamcmd +login anonymous +force_install_dir C:\Games\CSGOServer\TEST
pause
```

For some reason I get the following error upon running the file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a96eq.jpg (sorry, not enough rep to enbed with html)

Any ideas why start will not work given that it is clearly an accepted command? I did notice the strange characters in front of this but cannot really tell where these would come from.

Thanks in advance.

Damon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like someone saved that batch file in UTF-8 format. Open the file with Notepad and click *File → Save As...*. Change the field *Encoding* to "ANSI" and click *Save*. Confirm that you want to replace the file.

Comment: Hi mate. Thanks for this. The original batch file was created in vb.net by creating a text file and saving it as .bat. Is there a chance it did it at this stage?

Comment: Perhaps. I'm not familiar with VB.net, though, so I can't tell for certain.